# Los elementos se desestructuran en Google Chrome (sólo en Android)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Cuando cargo inicialmente la página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la vuelvo a cargar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, el botón de cerrar se ha deformado completamente

Esto **no me ocurre solamente con este botón**, también me ocurre en otros elementos y divisiones de otras secciones de la página web que les pasa algo parecido, pero en  vez de deformarse, se deslizan hacia la izquierda.

También se puede ver en el fondo negro como el botón de "Consultar", también se ha desestructurado.

**Esto solamente me sucede usando el navegador Google Chrome en dispositivos móviles (Android), pero sin embargo ni en Safari, ni en Opera, ni en Mozilla me ocurre esto.**

Aquí dejo el código de esta sección:

```css
#gradientbg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: ease 0.8s;
  -o-transition: ease 0.8s;
  transition: ease 0.8s;
}

#infoboxerror {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  background: #FF5555;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: ease 0.8s;
  -o-transition: ease 0.8s;
  transition: ease 0.8s;
}

#closebuttoninfoboxerror {
  color: #FF5555;
  font-size: 125px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}

#closebuttoninfoboxerror:hover {        
  box-shadow: none;
}

#infoerrorsection {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta id ="statusbarcolor" name="theme-color" content="#0092ED" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Error de asistente -->
    <div id="gradientbg"></div>
    <div id="infoboxerror">
      <i id="closebuttoninfoboxerror" class="material-icons">close</i><br><br>
      <div id="infoerrorsection">
        <h>El asistente personal no se encuentra disponible en estos momentos, por favor, vuelve a intentarlo más tarde</h><br><br>
        <h class="material-icons" style="font-size: 150px;">warning</h>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ya actualicé la pregunta @aldanux

Comment: Mete en `#closebuttoninfoboxerror` un `width: 125px;`... y me cuentas si te sirve

Comment: Buena sugerencia, pero si yo defino que el icono tenga un font-size de 125px, no quiere decir que su alto sean 125px, el font-size incluye más campo que el que ocupa este icono, a demás, como te digo en este caso lo deforma, en otros casos lo que hace es moverme los elementos hacia la izquierda @aldanux

Comment: No le estamos dando un alto.. `height`... lo que pasa es si no especificas el ancho al elemento te puede descuadrar en ciertos momentos porque intenta ocupar todo el ancho del elemento... yo lo he probado en el movil también y no da ningún problema... a parte de todo eso: `float: center;` no existe

Comment: Era el único caso en el que tenía `float: center`,m pero sigo sin entender por qué me mueve algunos elementos hacia la derecha, y solamente me pasa en chrome

Comment: Tambien tienes un fallo en tu HTML `<h>` sera un encabezado `<h1><h2>..<h6>`

Comment: ¿Puede ser que no se haya cargado la fuente del todo cuando se renderiza el elemento y por eso se vea así?¿o que la palabra cargada cuando no se ve bien no sea "close"?

Comment: Es cierto lo que dices, tiene mucho sentido, pero luego por ejemplo los botones que tienen un texto en el html pero luego sigue siendo el mismo texto una vez reenderizado, se mueven ligeramente hacia la izquierda como se puede ver en el botón de "Consultar" en el fondo oscurecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añadiendo esto al `<head>` se soluciona todo:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```